# Icons missing from IE11 debugger (F12)

Tags: javascript, debugging, internet-explorer

The IE11 Debugger tools do not show any icons in the top menu. Any idea how to fix this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try to [reset the IE browser setting](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/17441/windows-internet-explorer-change-reset-settings), if still not working, please try to [repair or re-install the IE browser](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/318378/how-to-repair-or-reinstall-internet-explorer-in-windows).